# Android - Gridview, custom layout onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView with two TextViews inside it, When the GridView is populated, an OnClickListener is set which returns the position of the item that was selected. I want to trigger a method when one of the TextViews is selected.

Is this possible? If yes, how do I set this up?

**EDIT 3**:

Inside my activity whch populated the GridView: I retrieve a `String-Array` from my `Strings.xml`, a `for loop` examines each item inside the Array and searches for a condition based on the Item's name inside the SharedPreferences, this `for loop` is solely for counting how many "true" conditions there are, so it retrieves a `int` saved inside the `count`. Then a new `String[]` is created, this required an exact length to be given before items can be added to it, so I check `count` if it's more than 0, it will give the `String[]` a length of `count` and then another `for loop` will add each `true` to the `String[]` list that we just created. If `count` is 0 (no true conditions found in the first `for loop`) then only 1 Item is added to the `String[]` and is given the value "No Favourites Added".

Then you have the GridView's OnItemClickListener().

```
        String s[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.FullList);
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            SharedPreferences sP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("fav", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Boolean b = sP.getBoolean(s[i], false);
            if (b == true) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        String[] newList;
        if (count > 0) {
            newList = new String[count];
            count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                SharedPreferences sP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("fav", MODE_PRIVATE);
                Boolean b = sP.getBoolean(s[i], false);
                if (b == true) {
                    newList[count] = s[i];
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newList = new String[1];
            newList[0] = "No favourites added";
        }

        GridView FavGV = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sexp_fav);
        FavGV.setAdapter(new Tab01_FavAdapter(getActivity(), newList));
        FavGV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, 
                    View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                //Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PosPreview_Gestures.class);
                //i.putExtra("position", position);
                //startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

So that's the code inside the Activity which populates the GridView. The Adapter in it's original, functioning form: This simply populates the GridView with Favourite Items (their names from the String[]) and adds a TextView with "Remove" which when pressed, shows a Toast: "Remove".

```
public class Tab01_FavAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    String mEntries[];     
    public Tab01_FavAdapter (Context c, String[] entries) {
        mContext = c;
        mInflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mEntries = entries; 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEntries.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.favitemlayout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tx = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favgridremoveitem);
        OnClickListener oCL = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Remove",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        tx.setOnClickListener(oCL);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added some code to my answer. Feel free to ask if something in the code isn't clear.

Comment: I have a few questions for you. Can you explain what the Grid items hold? Where are you using the `String` array `s`? In the line `final MyObjectClass info = mEntries.get(position);`, you need to change `MyObjectClass` to `String` and `mEntries` to `s`. Also, in the overridden `getItem(int position)` method, replace the `return position;` with `return s[position]`.

Comment: You also need the static ViewHolder class. Paste `public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tx;
    }` right after `String s[];`. Can you post the layout file `R.layout.favitemlayout`?

Comment: The GridView contains a list of Favourite items. The items are inside the s Array. When the GridView adapter is created inside the Activity, it passes the s Array to the adapter's constructor. Edit: each Item inside the gridview will have the name of the favourite and a TextView which says "Remove". When the name is pressed, it opens the Item - this is the GridView onClickListener inside my Activity. When Remove is pressed, it retrieves the Item name/pos of the GridView Item, and calls the favRemove() which will process that info and remove the item from the list.

Comment: Please see Edit 3 above. That's my original code with explanation of what it does. I need it to list my Favourite Items each with it's own Remove button (TextView) which, when pressed, calls the favRemove(String itemName, int itemPos). If however the Item itself is pressed (instead of the Remove button inside), I want it to trigger the OnItemClickListener: this is already set up as you can see in the Edit 3 code above. If you can get this part functioning, I'll take it from there :)

Comment: I realise that what I am trying to achieve is easy and there are numerous other easier ways to do it, but I'm a newbie and this was the only way I know how so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using a custom adapter for populating this `GridView`, and passing the `Context` as an argument to the constructor.

In the custom adapter, you should add `onClickListeners` to the `TextViews`. Using the context, you can call methods from your activity:

```
((CallingActivityName)context).methodYouWishToCall(parameters);
```

This would go inside the `onClickListeners`.

Edit: Added some code:

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<MyObjectClass> mEntries;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final Context mContext; 

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tx;
    }

    public MyGridAdapter(CallingActivityName context, List<MyObjectClass> entries) {
        super();
        mEntries = entries;
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEntries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mEntries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.favitemlayout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tx = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.favgridremoveitem);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final MyObjectClass info = mEntries.get(position);

        holder.tx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((CallingActivityName)mContext).favRemove(info);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

So, `CallingActivityName` is the name of the Activity where you initiate the adapter and where the method you need to call resides. `info` is the object held at position `position` of the gridview. `MyObjectClass` is the class name of the objects in the List `mEntries`.

Comment: PLease see EDIT above :)

Comment: I have a slight problem. I want to it up so that when the GridView's item is clicked, it triggers the onItemClickListener, but when the item's textview is clicked, it triggers this method that you have designed. Here is the Adapter, I tried to implment your code into it, but im lost. See Edit 2 above. I have only added the getView() code so far.