# Android twoWayGridView onItemClickListenter not working

Tags: android, android-gridview, two-way

I've implemented the [two-way-gridview library](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) by adding libs and two-way-gridview to my Android project.

The XML:

```
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
app:columnWidth="80dp"
app:rowHeight="80dp"
app:numColumns="3"
app:numRows="auto_fit"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
app:gravity="left" />
```

The Java code:

```
//set up adapter
CustomCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(context, cursor);
TwoWayGridView gridView = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

//assign adapter to ListView
gridView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

This happens:

1. Grid can scroll horizontally - yay!
2. All items are `TextViews` with the same element (the first item) - not yay.
3. No item in the grid is clickable - the `setOnItemClickListener` is not compatible - not yay.

Eclipse error:

> The method
>   setOnItemClickListener(TwoWayAdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the
>   type TwoWayAdapterView is not applicable for the
>   arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){})

on this piece of code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        //get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        //get the media file from this row in the database
        String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.FIELD_RESOURCE));

        String suffix = ".jpg";
        if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
            //Text item so do stuff for that

            }else if(fileName.endsWith(suffix)){
                    //Image item so do stuff for that

                }else {
                    //Video item so do stuff for that

                }
            }
        });
```

**Should I write a custom onItemClickListener for the two-way-gridview?**

Comment: I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17707452/956975 Any comments on that solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably just change :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {}
```

by

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new TwoWayAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {}
```